# How do I get a Wiimote working?

Tags: 12.04, wii

In kernel 3.1 the drive for the wiimote was added. Since 3.2 I ask, can I connect the wiimote and simply have access to it or do I need to install a program for it or something additional for it.

Comment: apparently you need a whole bunch of extra stuff - feel free to use this to create an answer Luis! https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XWiimote

Comment: Thanks for the direct info. I will make the guide since tomorrow I will be buying one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried WiiCan

Download .deb http://www.getdeb.net/software/wiican I know it was released for Natty

Here is the launchpad info https://launchpad.net/wiican

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fontanon/wiican
```

Evidentially it does a good job

```
Discover if it’s an available bluetooth device for connect wiimote
Display a list of available keyboard-mouse-wiimote mappings
User-defined mappings creation assistant
Mappings manager:

    New/Edit/Delete
    Up/Down order
    Visible/Invisible


Notify the state of wiimote usaging:

    Bluetooth available/unavailable
    Discovering wiimote
    Wiimote disconnected
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BlueXrider, but since a couple of changes where made for the Wii on the kernel I wanted to know how this will be handle in 12.04 and future versions.

Comment: It just works. (Wiican on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: The ppa mentioned only supports karmic. http://ppa.launchpad.net/fontanon/wiican/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: Apparently packaging has been "In progress" since 2009. I guess nobody cares about this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/501567 :(

Comment: For anyone else who hadn't heard of getdeb, you can't just click the getdeb link, you first have to go to http://www.getdeb.net/ and install getdeb on your system, then refresh the package cache (`sudo apt-get update`). Otherwise you just get a not found message from software centre.

Comment: @TimAbell Where did you find the PPA?  I couldn't find it on their launchpad site.  https://launchpad.net/wiican

Comment: @jumpnett I didn't, I used getdeb instead as I mentioned. http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/12.04#how_to_install then http://www.getdeb.net/software/wiican